# Join 3 table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**table 1 name : nfc_film**

Column Name = id, film_id, title, description

**table 2 name : nfc_film_actor**

Column name = id, actor_id, film_id

**table 3 name : nfc_actor**

Column name = actor_id, first_name, last_name

**Question :** How can I join this 3 table together?

I want get the value first_name and last_name from table **nfc_actor** but my query doesn't work.

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM nfc_film 
INNER JOIN nfc_film_actor ON 
    nfc_film_actor.film_id = nfc_film.film_id 
INNER JOIN nfc_actor ON 
    nfc_actor.actor_id = nfc_film_actor.actor_id 
WHERE nfc_film.film_id = :filmid
```

Comment: What is the result of this query? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Seems like the request is ok to me. Maybe you could show us a little more of your code and the output of the query.

Comment: What is this `:filmid` ? It's wrong!

Comment: show how do you preparing parameter `:filmid` and how do you send that query

Comment: please post the error you are facing. It will help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `*` selector in your query, because id, actor_id and film_id exist in multiple tables, this definitely wrong.
You should refer to the specific name of each field.

If you check your web-server `error.log` you can see that.

Maybe did you mean:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM nfc_film 
INNER JOIN nfc_film_actor
  ON nfc_film_actor.film_id = nfc_film.film_id 
INNER JOIN nfc_actor
  ON nfc_actor.actor_id = nfc_film_actor.actor_id 
WHERE nfc_film.film_id = nfc_film_actor.film_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 SELECT  nfc_actor.first_name,nfc_actor.last_name,
FROM nfc_film 
INNER JOIN nfc_film_actor 
ON nfc_film_actor.film_id = nfc_film.film_id 
INNER JOIN nfc_actor 
ON nfc_actor.actor_id = nfc_film_actor.actor_id 
WHERE nfc_film.film_id = 'some_id';
```

give id of film in the place of 'some_id'